# BigQuery - unsupported subquery with table in join predicate

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Recently I started to work on BigQuery and there's something that makes me still confused.
What's the alternative for this query on Big Query?

```
select a.abc, c.xyz
from table1 as a
left join table2 as c
on a.abc = c.abc
and c.date = (select t.date from table3 t)
```

The things is that Big Query doesn't support the subquery in join. I've tried many alternatives but the result doesn't match to each other.

Comment: I  believe it do support in `Standard SQL`

Comment: @Tushar I think It doesn't because I added `#standardSQL` and it still got an error

Comment: @hushhush Add to the question the query you are running in BQ and also the error

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `table3.date` is unique, try writing the query like this:

```
select a.abc, c.xyz
from table1 a left join
     (table2 c join
      table3 t
      on c.date = t.date
     )
     on a.abc = c.abc;
```

If there are duplicates in `table3`, you can phrase this as:

```
select a.abc, c.xyz
from table1 a left join
     (table2 c join
      (select distinct date
       from table3 t
      ) t
      on c.date = t.date
     )
     on a.abc = c.abc;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with clause` to resolve this issue,

```
WITH TEMP_TB(select t.date as date from table3 t) 
select a.abc, c.xyz
from table1 as a 
left join table2 as c
on a.abc = c.abc
left join c.date = TEMP_TB.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed at the moment subqueries are not supported in join predicate.

If you really need this you can [file Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/getting-support#issuetracker) for that. I am sure that many people will be happy with it.

There is a workaround. You can make a script of it, something like:

```
declare date TIMESTAMP;
set date = (select t.date from table3 t);

select a.abc, c.xyz
from table1 as a
left join table2 as c
on a.abc = c.abc
and c.date = date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this part fully, but if your usecase permits this, it seems like I could get this working:

```
SELECT a.abc, c.xyz
FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN table2 as c
ON a.abc = c.abc
WHERE c.date = (select t.date from table3 t)
```

Again, it's quite possible that it could decrease query performance since I am not sure if WHERE() is applied after the JOIN() is complete, which means a more expensive query. For my usecase, it worked well.